# How can I undersample the number of data points that are uniformly distributed on a sphere by keeping the uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, under-sampling

Given uniform distributed random numbers on a sphere, how can I undersample it, so reduce the number of data points and obtain a subset which keeps the uniform distribution ?

I tried to search on Google but I find only ways to generate a uniform distribution on a unit sphere...

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Enumerate the numbers and sample randomly from that frame without replacement.  This assumes "uniform" and "distribution" refer to the *data-generating process,* not the points themselves.  If you really mean the points, then there are only five possible sets of points that could be considered uniform (up to rotation and reflection): namely, the vertices of a Platonic solid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sampling method you could just generate fewer samples. If you have independent samples, you could just take the first $k$ samples to have less samples.

Comment: I must start from the biggest set and then decrease.

Comment: If these samples are independent, then you can just take any subset, e.g. the first $k$ samples.